# 0/1 Knapsack witness generation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have written a knapsack class which I am using to solve the knapsack algorithm. The class works and is using the dynamic programming algorithm to solve the problem.

I have implemented some optimizations in the code so that I take linear O(W) space to find the maximum value but when I try to find the witness I still need O(nW) space to keep the table of booleans.

Could someone tell me if it is possible to find the witness for the knapsack with maximum capacity with smaller amount of space and with the same complexity of O(nW), here W is the knapsack capacity.

If you think there might be some more optimizations in the code please tell them as well.

```
class Knapsack{
private:
  vector< int > value, weight, answer, DP;
  vector< bool > isin;
  int capacity;

public:
  Knapsack( vector< int > value, vector< int > weight, int capacity, bool needWitness ){
    this->value = value;
    this->weight = weight;
    this->capacity = capacity;

    this->answer.clear(); this->isin.clear(); this->DP.clear();
    this->DP.resize( capacity + 1, false );

    if ( needWitness ){
      this->isin.resize( value.size() * (capacity + 1), false );
      solveWithWitness();
    }
    else{
      solveWithoutWitness();
    }

  }

  void solveWithoutWitness(){
    for ( int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++ ){
      for ( int w = capacity; w >= weight[i]; w-- ){
        if ( DP[w] < value[i] + DP[w - weight[i]] ){
          DP[w] = value[i] + DP[w - weight[i]];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void solveWithWitness(){
    for ( int i = 0; i < value.size(); i++ ){
      for ( int w = capacity; w >= weight[i]; w-- ){
        if ( DP[w] < value[i] + DP[w - weight[i]] ){
          DP[w] = value[i] + DP[w - weight[i]];
          isin[ i*capacity + w ] = true;
        }
      }
    }
    int position = value.size()-1;
    int w = capacity;
    while ( position >= 0 ){
      if ( isin[ position*capacity + w ] ){
        answer.push_back( position );
        w -= weight[position];
      }
      position--;
    }
  }


  vector< int > getWitness(){
    return this->answer;
  }

  int solution(){
    return DP[capacity];
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using O's all over the place, so I can give you a theory solution that's a bit complicated and awkward that still satisfies the time bounds you want:

Run the without-witness DP for n/2 steps; that tells you which of the W weights is reachable using only the first n/2 items.  Now run a DP for the remaining n/2 steps keeping track of how much weight is needed from the first n/2 items to reach each cell.

If you naively apply this procedure in a recursive way, you get a time recurrences looking like T(n, W) <= 2T(n/2, W) + O(nW), whose solution is O(n log(n) W).  That's not quite good enough.

But we worked out how much weight was needed from the first n/2 items.  Call that w.  We only need to care about the first w entries of the DP array.  So the first-half recursion should take T(n/2, w) time, the second-half recursion should take T(n/2, W-w) time, and the work needed to get there takes O(nW) time.

The solution to a recurrence of the form T(n, W) <= max(0 <= w <= W) T(n/2, w) + T(n/2, W-w) + O(nW) is actually O(nW).  You can see this intuitively by imagining an n-by-W rectangle initially of zeroes.  A recursive knapsack call with n' items and weight W' adds 1 to each entry in some n'-by-W' subrectangle.  Then the first level of recursion adds a total of nW, the second level nW/2, the third nW/4, and so forth, giving you a geometric series.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You have said "Now run a DP for the remaining n/2 steps keeping track of how much weight is needed from the first n/2 items to reach each cell". Could you explain this step in more detail?

Comment: It's similar to the with-witness DP, except you only keep track of the cell-after-n/2-items instead of a whole chain of back-pointers.